# session active PHP, check in LOOP?

Tags: php, session

I have this function which I am using at the beginning of every of my PHP pages, which is working fine, if time has expired, the next CLICK on the page it will go out fine and go to usuarioLoginLogout.php.

```
function verificarSiEstoyConectado()
{
    if( $_SESSION['last_activity'] < time()-$_SESSION['expire_time'] )
    {
        header('Location: usuarioLoginLogout.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
    }
}
```

In my welcome page, I'm settings session variable as follows:

```
$_SESSION['logged_in']     = true;
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
$_SESSION['expire_time']   = 60*3;
```

My doubt is if exists any way to check that function but in a LOOP, not to wait to the user to do click in any link of my site in order to check at the beginning of any page that if has expired or not?

If it possible, how could I implement this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: why would your server care about what happens in the user's browser? The session is there to make sure that requests to the server are handled correctly, if the user doesn't ask the server anything, why would the server do anything?

Comment: It's not clear when you want to do this check. Why would you put it in a loop? That would be unnecessary processing. Simply make this check on every page load (preferably as an include)

Comment: William, I would like the webpage automatically logged off, instead of waiting to the user access to some link and then it will logged off, because it is as a function which is being called in the beggining of every page.

I want to implement this, because I have a table with users, and I will like to have a datetime with "connection date" and "disconnection date", which works only if the user press a link in the page and then it will be send to log off.  Otherwise, database will not know if was logged off and I will not have "disconnection date".

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to check whether the user session has expired and if so, redirect them to the login page? This cannot be done on the server side. You can achieve that with a session timer on the client side with Javascript. When the JS timer runs out you would redirect them to a logout page, which will log them out.

Comment: AtomCode, I saw this, you were right, JS with setTimeout it will work.
But, what happened if the user close the window before it expires? It seams like I will not be able to check when it was disconected, right?